# How to use @sentry/node in razzle express server file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sentry, razzle

According to [sentry's docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/) the setup for node is just

```js
// server.js
const Sentry = require("@sentry/node");

Sentry.init({ dsn: "https://1df8da5e900e440e8d6e767ec6277ff9@o126849.ingest.sentry.io/296346" });
```

However, when I run `razzle start` I get this

```
TypeError: mod.require is not a function

    at dynamicRequire (/Users/daniellizik/foo/node_modules/@sentry/utils/esm/node.js:19:1)
    at getDefaultSamplingContext (/Users/daniellizik/foo/build/webpack:/node_modules/@sentry/tracing/esm/hubextensions.js:107:1)
    at Hub._startTransaction (/Users/daniellizik/foo/build/webpack:/node_modules/@sentry/tracing/esm/hubextensions.js:162:1)
    at Hub.module.exports../node_modules/@sentry/hub/esm/hub.js.Hub._callExtensionMethod (/Users/daniellizik/foo/build/webpack:/node_modules/@sentry/hub/esm/hub.js:348:1)
    at Hub.module.exports../node_modules/@sentry/hub/esm/hub.js.Hub.startTransaction (/Users/daniellizik/foo/build/webpack:/node_modules/@sentry/hub/esm/hub.js:308:1)
    at callOnHub (/Users/daniellizik/foo/build/webpack:/node_modules/@sentry/minimal/esm/index.js:17:1)
    at startTransaction (/Users/daniellizik/foo/build/webpack:/node_modules/@sentry/minimal/esm/index.js:189:1)
```

There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/951) in the sentry repo for universal apps, but no solution is provided.

Answer (score 0):

These deps seem to work now with universal js apps

```
"@sentry/browser": "6.8.0",
"@sentry/node": "6.8.0",
"@sentry/tracing": "6.8.0"
```